# Browser not blocking popups

Tags: browser, google-chrome

I have disable showing popups for all sites in my chrome browser. But when I visit http://www.hdfcbank.com/ and click *Login* , it show a pop up window. Why chrome is not blocking this? Are there some default exceptions in blocking popups or is it some kind of bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.open` is only regarded as a popup when not initiated by a user action, including `onclick`. [Related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816127/blocked-vs-non-blocked-pop-up-window)

If it is an advertisement and you have adblock software, you can add defining characteristics of the advertisement's url to your custom blacklist.